# How to generate a private key from a encrypted pirvate key?

Tags: ssl, certificate, haproxy, private-key

I got a encrypted private key and a cert-bundle (cert.pem).
I need a private key instead of the encrypted one.

I tried generating the private key from the encrypted running this command:

```
openssl pkey -in encrypted.key -out key.pem
```

But when I load this decrypted_private.key I'm getting an error:
"inconsistencies between private key and certificate loaded"

I've run the following commands and the values does not match:

```
openssl pkey -in key.pem -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the private key in `key.pem` and the public key in `cert.pem` come from different keypairs.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk well the key.pem was generated from the encrypted.key that belongs to cert.pem.

Comment: What kind of key? You could try and parse the (decrypted) key and the certificate using `asn1parse` command or by looking at the output. For RSA the modulus should be identical for them to be from the same key pair.

Comment: You may think they're for the same keypair, but they're not. Try `openssl s_server -cert cert.pem -key encrypted.key -accept $some_unused_port` and (after you give the password) I bet it will confirm they don't match. One possibility: check if _your_ cert (aka the leaf or end-entity/EE cert) is the _first_ one in cert.pem; some servers use a cert chain in a single PEM file, but often require the EE cert first, and `openssl x509` only reads one cert and ignores any others. @Maarten: easier and more general `openssl pkey -in privkey -text; openssl pkey -in pubkey -pubin -text`

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes they are not identical so it was a huge hint there.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 "You may think they're for the same keypair, but they're not" this was def the key to solve this. I trusted the certificates I was provided and did not check that they were not the same keypair.

This helped me solve it. Had to grab the same keypairs and that worked.

Thanks all!